# VueJs Axios Post FormData Parameters

Tags: json, spring, vue.js, axios

We are using Vue in our frontend application, and for one of our REST service our backend server(using spring and java) expects to have the below data structure:

```
public class MAProductsUploadRequest
{
    public List<MAProductUploadRequest> products;
}

public class MAProductUploadRequest {

    public String productName;
    public String productDescription;
    public double productPrice;
    public int productOrder;
    public MultipartFile productImage=null;
    public double cropX;
    public double cropY;
    public double cropWidth;
    public double cropHeight;
    public int categoryId;
}
```

And in our Vuejs application we tried to post the data as in the below code:

```
      addProducts: function () {
        console.log("Add Products Working. Total Product Count:"+this.excelProducts.length);
        let header = {
          headers: auth.getAuthHeader()
        };

        let formData = new FormData();

        for (let i=0;i<this.excelProducts.length;i++ ) {

           console.log("Starting loop:"+i);
           var prod = this.excelProducts[i];
           console.log("Product Before:"+prod);
           if (document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i) !== null) {
             if(document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i).files.length !== 0) {
               console.log("Getting Image For Prod");
               prod.productImage = document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i).files[0] ;
             }
           }

          prod.cropX = this.cropProp.x;
          prod.cropY = this.cropProp.y;
          prod.cropWidth = this.cropProp.width;
          prod.cropHeight = this.cropProp.height;
          prod.rotate = this.cropProp.rotate;


          console.log("Product After:"+prod);
          formData.append("products[]",prod);

        }

        for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
          console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
        }

        //console.log("Form Data:"+formData.products);

        if (formData.products !== null) {
          axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/uploadProducts`, formData, header).then((response) => {
            logForDevelopment(response);
            this.getProducts();
            this.product = {
              id: '',
              name: '',
              description: '',
              price: '',
              photo: '',
              isEdit: false
            };
            this.excelProducts = [];
            this.isPhotoChosen = false;
            this.isPhotosChosen = [];
            this.cropImg = '';
            document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
            this.isLoading = false;
          }).catch((error) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            if(error.response) {
              logForDevelopment(error);
              document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
              if(error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                auth.afterInvalidToken('login');
              }
            }
          })
        }  else {
          console.log("Form Data Is Empty");
        }



      },
```

But when we use this code (even if the photo-image was null) the backend server returns HTTP 500 error. Because the products array seems null.
I wasn't able to figure it out where the problem may be in the Vuejs code?

**EDIT: (I'VE also tried the below code but the still same result)**

```
      addProducts: function () {
        console.log("Add Products Working. Total Product Count:"+this.excelProducts.length);
        let header = {
          headers: auth.getAuthHeader()
        };

        let formData = new FormData();
        let prods = [];

        for (let i=0;i<this.excelProducts.length;i++ ) {

           console.log("Starting loop:"+i);
           let prod = this.excelProducts[i];


           let subFormData = new FormData();
           subFormData.append("productName",prod.productName);
           subFormData.append("productDescription",prod.productDescription);
           subFormData.append("productPrice",prod.price);
           subFormData.append("categoryId",prod.categoryId);
           subFormData.append("cropX",this.cropProp.x);
           subFormData.append("cropY",this.cropProp.y);
           subFormData.append("cropWidth",this.cropProp.width);
           subFormData.append("cropHeight",this.cropProp.height);

           prods.push(subFormData);



           if (document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i) !== null) {
             if(document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i).files.length !== 0) {
               console.log("Getting Image For Prod");
               subFormData.productImage = document.getElementById('photo-image-'+i).files[0] ;
             }
           }


        }

        formData.append("products",prods);

        console.log("Form Data:"+formData);

        if (formData.products !== null) {
          axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/uploadProducts`, formData, header).then((response) => {
            logForDevelopment(response);
            this.getProducts();
            this.product = {
              id: '',
              name: '',
              description: '',
              price: '',
              photo: '',
              isEdit: false
            };
            this.excelProducts = [];
            this.isPhotoChosen = false;
            this.isPhotosChosen = [];
            this.cropImg = '';
            document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
            this.isLoading = false;
          }).catch((error) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            if(error.response) {
              logForDevelopment(error);
              //document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
              if(error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                auth.afterInvalidToken('login');
              }
            }
          })
        }  else {
          console.log("Form Data Is Empty");
        }



      },
```

**What I'm actually trying to achive is, our below code works fine when sending single product info to our backend service, but I want to make it an array so send multiple products at once:**

```
      addProduct: function () {

        let header = {
          headers: auth.getAuthHeader()
        };

        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('productName', this.product.name);
        formData.append('productDescription', this.product.description === '' ? "" : this.product.description);
        formData.append('productPrice', this.product.price);
        formData.append('categoryId', this.product.categoryId);
        if(document.getElementById('photo-image').files.length !== 0) {
          formData.append('productImage', document.getElementById('photo-image').files[0]);
        }
        formData.append('cropX', this.cropProp.x);
        formData.append('cropY', this.cropProp.y);
        formData.append('cropWidth', this.cropProp.width);
        formData.append('cropHeight', this.cropProp.height);
        formData.append('rotate', this.cropProp.rotate);

        console.log(formData);

        axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/products`, formData, header).then((response) => {
          logForDevelopment(response);
          this.getProducts();
          this.product = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: '',
            price: '',
            photo: '',
            isEdit: false
          };
          this.isPhotoChosen = false;
          this.cropImg = '';
          document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
          this.isLoading = false;
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          if(error.response) {
            logForDevelopment(error);
            document.getElementById('photo-image').value = null;
            if(error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
              auth.afterInvalidToken('login');
            }
          }
        })

      },
```

Does anyone have any idea about that?

You can also look at the screenshot of my application in below(I want to send all the items in screenshot , at once )

[image]

Comment: Did not you press F12 to open the DevTools and see what exactly is being sent by XHR ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably il the `formData.append("products[]",prod)` method of your `FormData` class, try changing `formData.append("products[]",prod)` with `formData.products.push(prod)`.

Furthermore in your axios call the payload should be formData.products if you API endpoint expects the products right?
Try `axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/uploadProducts`, formData.products, header)`.

I do not see any syntax issue relative to Vue, hope this helps. (And of course check what is sent by XHR in devtools as suggested in the comments)

Comment: I've edited my first post and attached the code I've tried according to your suggestion, but still same result in backend side

Comment: You are still passing only `formData` as payload data in you axios post call, is this intentional? Should you not send `formData.products` to your backend instead?

Comment: yes because in our spring backendservice, it expects an array named products(You can see our backend structure it on top of the first topic), And I guess the actual problem is , I cannot create the model properly in vuejs client side

Comment: I've also edited my code and put some bold lines in it , so you can see what I'm actually trying to achieve here

Comment: Sorry, but to my understanding this call `axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/uploadProducts`, formData, header)` sends an object (`formData`). So, **if you want to send an array as you say**, you should send `axios.post(`${API_URL}/company/uploadProducts`, formData.products, header)`, --> `formData.products` is the array you are talking about. Then of course your backend must be able to handle an array instead of an object (JSON) otherwise it will "crash".